# Custom theme - Cannot find code to change text

Tags: magento2, code, custom-theme

I've downloaded a custom theme for my Magento 2 site and would like to know where some files are generally located such as the "Save 60% off sale" text or the "find your next Magento 2 theme". I've managed to change the color of buttons and other variables in the .less files, however, I cannot find everything here. I was wondering if there is any other likely location that they may be. I've also looked a lot on the Magento dashboard options but still no look.

I'm using the hiddentechies bizkick theme.

I appreciate that my question is very vague however any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should ask the theme vendor instead.

Comment: Check static block section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the text "Save 60% off sale" from the static block.

Go to Content -> Static Blocks from admin and find the static block "Home Images Block" with an identifier "home-images-two" and edit text and save this static block. After this flush cache.

You can change the text "Find Your Next Magento 2 Theme" from the static block.

Go to Content -> Static Blocks from admin and find the static block "Home Extension Slider" with an identifier "home-extension-slider" and edit text and save this static block. After this flush cache.